# Nexus 5X recovery via fastboot or adb?

Tags: adb, fastboot, nexus

Has just crashed and refused to turn on reliably, gets to white google logo and switches off. Occasionally gets to Fastboot menu, but never gets to recovery menu
I suspect battery issue, although I have power cable connected, and was on 70% when it crashed

Erase the current recovery by using fastboot:  fastboot erase recovery
Flash the recovery.img file using fastboot:  fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
Now you've flashed a fresh recovery image to your device. You can do this without losing any data, and if you use a custom recovery like TWRP, these instructions apply as well. I do this all the time when I reload the stock software on my Nexus 6.

Running latest Ubuntu GNU/Linux on laptop
android-tools-adb                                    5.1.1r36+git20160322-0ubun
android-tools-fastboot                               5.1.1r36+git20160322-0ubuntu3

Google LG Nexus 5X, running latest updates.

But isn't showing up as a device I can use by fastboot or adb

```
$ lsusb
show one extra device:
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 05c6:9008 Qualcomm, Inc. Gobi Wireless Modem (QDL mode)
```

```
Apr 29 15:04:59 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157627.493587] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Apr 29 15:05:04 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157632.606057] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr 29 15:05:19 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157647.823323] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr 29 15:05:19 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157648.039307] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Apr 29 15:05:25 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157653.151722] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr 29 15:05:35 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157663.392584] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Apr 29 15:05:40 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157668.505031] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr 29 15:05:55 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157683.722224] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr 29 15:05:55 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157683.938212] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Apr 29 15:06:00 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157689.050650] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr 29 15:06:16 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157704.267841] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr 29 15:06:16 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157704.483826] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
Apr 29 15:06:21 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157709.500278] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Apr 29 15:06:26 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157714.716594] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Apr 29 15:06:26 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157714.920605] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 10, error -62
Apr 29 15:06:26 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157715.032581] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
Apr 29 15:06:31 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157720.045014] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Apr 29 15:06:37 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157725.261441] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Apr 29 15:06:37 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157725.465430] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 11, error -62
Apr 29 15:06:37 ubuntu1404 kernel: [157725.465488] usb usb3-port1: unable to enumerate USB device


Apr 29 15:22:20 ubuntu1404 kernel: [158668.754673] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
Apr 29 15:22:20 ubuntu1404 kernel: [158668.885855] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=9008
Apr 29 15:22:20 ubuntu1404 kernel: [158668.885862] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Apr 29 15:22:20 ubuntu1404 kernel: [158668.885865] usb 3-1: Product: QHSUSB__BULK
Apr 29 15:22:20 ubuntu1404 kernel: [158668.885868] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
Apr 29 15:22:20 ubuntu1404 kernel: [158668.887133] qcserial 3-1:1.0: Qualcomm USB modem converter detected
Apr 29 15:22:20 ubuntu1404 kernel: [158668.887354] usb 3-1: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Apr 29 15:22:20 ubuntu1404 mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 12: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1"
Apr 29 15:22:20 ubuntu1404 mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 12 was not an MTP device
Apr 29 15:22:22 ubuntu1404 kernel: [158670.847529] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 12
Apr 29 15:22:22 ubuntu1404 kernel: [158670.847868] qcserial ttyUSB0: Qualcomm USB modem converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Apr 29 15:22:22 ubuntu1404 kernel: [158670.847914] qcserial 3-1:1.0: device disconnected
```

Are the flashing red led codes any information? (5) (12) (35)

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Can you make it stay in fastboot? And run `fastboot devices`

Comment: Hi Sumeet. Thank you for your reply. I've not been able to get it to switch on for last two days. The red LED in the lower speaker flashes. Does that mean not enough power to switch on? Could indicate low power?    I wondered if that "Qualcomm, Inc. Gobi Wireless Modem (QDL mode)" message, means that it is stuck not charging, and stuck in some kind of firmware mode.

Comment: Nexus 5X has an internal battery (not user replaceable) but I found online how to take cover off. Is it worth trying to disconnect the battery, to force a reset?

Comment: maybe that will work, but my knowledge on hardware issues would be based on guesses and nothing else

Comment: Tried to connect to the  Quallcom QDL serial device, but no luck with a few baud rates
microcom -s 38400 -p /dev/ttyUSB0

Comment: Hi. I carefully look off the cover, earthed myself, and disconnected battery for 1 minute. Reconnected, but same problem when reassembled.  I might buy replacement LG BL-T19 battery, or borrow one

Comment: borrowing is a good idea, because if it's not a battery problem then you'd save a lot of money but then again your name is *rich*, have you tried going to LG support? (it's also an LG device)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Yes LG provide 2 year warranty, however they told me all data is lost. So that is not much use alone, I didn't sync holiday photos :-(    I wonder if it is just the charging circuit. Doesn't even turn on now, just the flashing red light within speaker. Do you know what that means?

Comment: No but if it was a problem with micro USB then it would not have been recognized in your `lsusb`, right?

Comment: Good point Sumeet! Yes, if USB data connection is working, it would be surprising if charging was also broken.. although charging circuit may be separate. Usually separate powermangement chip (I am an embedded software developer).  Certainly the device is stuck in Broadcomm QDL mode..

Comment: That might be the case